# ModelState Errors not showing in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action that saves a record by calling my BLL entity's Save method. The entity takes care of its own internal validation and if a field is required but fails validation because a user didn't enter a value then the entity throws up an error. I'm catching that error in my action and returning the same view. The problem is the error isn't showing in my ValidationSummary.

Yes I realize I have view model validation by attibute with MVC but this entity is used elsewhere and must have redundant validation if the UI doesn't/can't do it, such as used in a batch service job.

Here is my action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(EntityModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var entity = new Entity(model.ID, model.Name, model.IsActive);
        try {
            entity.Save(User.Identity.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model ELM.Select.Web.Models.EntityModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>DefermentTypeViewModel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Why wouldn't the error I add to modelstate be shown in my validationsummary?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change your View code:

`@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

to:

`@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`

As per [the MSDN Reference on ValidationSummary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839469.aspx), here is the method definition:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    bool excludePropertyErrors
)
```

Notice that the `bool` parameter, if you set it to `true` (like you originally did) you will exclude property errors.  Change that to `false` and that should get you what you want.

Comment: I know this is old and all, but am I the only one confused and doesn't really think this is the answer? The bool param is `excludePropertyErrors`. The method used to add an error is `ModelState.AddModelError` - so we add a **model** error and we exclude **property** errors, so what is the problem? Why does showing **property** errors display the added **model** error? It is either a bug in the validation summary or a poorly named ModelState method, right?